# Returning a 403 status code in Service Stack

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack

I have a web service using service stack and I'm putting in a blacklist check to stop the processing of requests from a list of the blacklisted IP addresses.

How do I return a 403 status code back to the user?

Here's what I've tried so far.

```
public static CustomHttpResult CheckIfIPIsBlackListed(string ipAddress)
        {
            try
            {
                DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
                int resultCount = (from r in db.WebService_BlackLists
                                   where r.BlackList_IPAddress == ipAddress
                                   select r).Count();

                //check if we have 1 or more record
                if(resultCount >= 1)
                {
                    return CustomHttpResult[HttpStatusCode.Forbidden];
                }

                return null;
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: off-topic comment: I would move this to network layer(by cutting off traffic from such IP on router)

Comment: did you tried first google result like `throw new HttpError(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Some Error Message");`

Comment: From there github: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Error-Handling#returning-a-httperror

Comment: Thanks everyone.

So i've added the following:

if(CommonFunctions.CheckIfIPIsBlackListed(userSession.RequestIP)) { throw new HttpError(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, "Forbidden"); }

To the Interface that receives the request and seems to be working.

Answer (score 2):

Inside a Service you can [throw a HttpError](https://docs.servicestack.net/error-handling#returning-a-httperror) (or return), e.g:

```
throw HttpError.Forbidden("Thou shall not pass");
```

Inside a filter you can [short-circuit the Request with a HTTP Error](https://docs.servicestack.net/error-handling#custom-http-errors) with:

```
res.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
res.StatusDescription = "Thou shall not pass";
res.EndRequest();
```

Comment: Oh, neat, I didn't know about the HttpError, there's so many cases that I would have used that.